# Is "Life Recovery" from flasks the same as "Life Regeneration" from passives?

Tags: path-of-exile

For example: Would [Zealot's Oath](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Zealot%27s_Oath) work with flasks or is it a seperate regeneration type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zealot's Oath will not cause Energy Shield to regenerate when using Life Flasks. Flasks *recover* life rather than regenerating it. Regeneration and Recovery are treated entirely separately despite having similar effects

As a nail in the coffin [here's a quote](http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/81592#p926402) from Mark_GGG, one of the developers:

> "Much more interesting for me is, whether it works with fixed amounts,
>   too. Like the Armour and trinket affixes. Because that could be real
>   strong. And awesome." - Cazychel
>
> Yes, all life regeneration. Note that flasks and leech, among other
>   things are not regneration. But anything which says it's life
>   regeneration will work with ZO

Comment: Uff... I hope this isnt true. Do you have more information to support your version? I mean did someone test it for real? Why does life recover flasks increase my life regeneration?

Comment: @StephanSchielke There are many posts in the forum by people saying it doesn't work. This was the only post I could find by an official skill developer from GGG. If he is wrong then this would be a bug which would soon be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

The flask "recovery" is not quiet the same as life regeneration. I just tested it.

The flask will increase your life-regeneration for X seconds:

[image: flask regeneration]

However... this will not work with Zealot. 
Zealot will **NOT** work with flasks and restore your energy shield, even if your ES-Recovery is triggered. I just tested this too. Your flask will heal your life and not your ES. Even if you trigger a flask during your normal ES-regeneration this will have effect at all to your ES-regeneration/s. The flask still regenerates your life.

Your normal life regeneration will be converted to a constant ES regen with Zealot:
[image]

Comment: Could be a suggestion that you can make to the game maker. It's still in beta remember?